# How to restrict a single php file from getting directly?

Tags: php

I need to restrict a particular php file from directly getting accessed. Not through htaccess any other method please.

Comment: if you don't want it directly accessed, then DON'T PUT IT IN YOUR DOCUMENT ROOT.

Comment: So... through no method? Typically you put things like classes in a private folder.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Put a webpage up that people can't access via a web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put a constant inside the root file that loads "childfile". After you try to access the childfile.php directly, it dies on the access error, because that constant is not defined.

Root file:

```
<?php

define('LOADED', TRUE);

include('childfile.php');
...
```

childfile.php:

```
<?php

if( !defined('LOADED') )
   die('You cannot access this file directly!');

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the PHP file in a directory that is outside of your web root (ie- higher up the structure than htdocs/ or www/ or whatever you're using). You can still require it in PHP, but it can't be accessed by HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to define a constant (e.g. 'APPLICATION') in a common file and then, in the file you don't want directly accessed put:

`if(!defined('APPLICATION')){ die("Don't look at me!");  }`